# I don't understand how cache work's on GAE python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've a problem with Google App engine, when I push data in my ndb, I see it in the datastore viewer, but when I try to see it in my website, that doesn't work's, but I just make a simple query like:

```
def my_query(self)
    return self.query()
```

I think it's because the ndb have a cache system but I dont find how it work's.

I'm really disapointed about that...

PS: I use "gae-boilerplate" if that make any difference :/
PS-1: Sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: It won't be caching that is the problem. Have a read up on Eventual Consistency first that is more than likely your problem.

Comment: yes. not related to caching.